# How can I set the boot order when I only have a wireless keyboard?

Tags: windows, bios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use bluetooth keyboard to access/edit BIOS?](https://superuser.com/questions/242457/use-bluetooth-keyboard-to-access-edit-bios)

One of my friend wanted to format her computer, but she can't boot from a CD as the hard disk has higher priority in the BIOS. The BIOS can't be accessed as she has a wireless keyboard which is only detected after the OS boots up.

Is there someway we can modify that setting from within Windows so as to boot from CD/USB?

Answer (score 1):

Plug in a physical PS/2 keyboard, and enable USB keyboard support in the BIOS. You should then be able to use the wireless keyboard to enter the BIOS later.

If the machine is a real antique, it may not have this option. In that case you'll just have to make the settings changes with the PS/2 keyboard attached.

If it's a Bluetooth keyboard, you're out of luck.